# Visual Studio 2012 - Copy "Views" and "Content" to project Output Path

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2012, msbuild

I have an MVC project and would like to have the build output to a different directory.  I have set the **Output Path** in the project properties and this takes care of where all the .DLL's are deployed but how do I have my **Views** and **Content** folders move there as well?

I realize I could use post-build events to move the files but I feel like there is an easier way (which I may have done before...).

Comment: Does [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13575551/147211) work for you?

Comment: @KMoraz Thanks.  I did see that one but it seemed a little off to me.  I answered my own question below.

Answer (score 2):

I ended up going with **Post-build events** because it was easy enough...

```
Robocopy $(ProjectDir)Views $(TargetDir)..\Views /s
Robocopy $(ProjectDir)Content $(TargetDir)..\Content /s
Copy $(ProjectDir)Web.config $(TargetDir)..\Web.config
```

This will still use *output path* variable set within the Visual Studio project properties. This was important to me because some team members are quite junior and I would like the set-up process to be straight forward.

Answer (score 1):

A bit late but I think you need to set 'WebProjectOutputDir' too. For my project I have:

```
WebProjectOutputDir=ReleaseFolder
```

and

```
OutDir=ReleaseFolder\bin
```

Comment: This works, and should probably be marked as the accepted answer. I just added `<WebProjectOutputDir>$(OutputPath)\foo</WebProjectOutputDir>` to my `.csproj` file.Thanks!