# VS C# Project: How to organize 3rd Party DLLs used by DllImport

Tags: c#, c++, visual-studio, dll

I have a Visual Studio C# project that utilizes 3rd party C++ DLLs. Up until now there have been only 3 of these DLLs and so it hasn't bothered me to place these in the root folder of my project with the following properties:

```
Build Action: None
Copy to Output Directory: Copy Always
```

This results in the DLLs being copied to the project's `/bin` folder and all works fine - they do not appear in the published project's root folder. I reference these 3rd party DLLs like this:

```
public class MyDLL
{
    [DllImport("My_DLL.dll",
        EntryPoint = "?Unit@@YA?AUOutput@@UInput@@@Z",
        CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
    public static extern MyDLLOutput Unit(MyDLLInput UnitInput);
}
```

Recently I've been provided with several dozens of additional DLLs. I do not reference these directly from within my app - these DLLs are used by one of the 3 DLLs I reference using `DllImport()`.

Placing all of these support DLLs in the root folder of the project now becomes an issue with me as it clutters the project. I've tried placing them inside a folder structure such as:

```
/ExternalDLLs/DLL1/dll1.dll
/ExternalDLLs/DLL1/SupportDlls/1.dll
...
/ExternalDLLs/DLL1/SupportDlls/24.dll
/ExternalDLLs/DLL2/dll2.dll
/ExternalDLLs/DLL3/dll3.dll
```

This results in a published folder structure of:

```
/bin/ExternalDLLs/DLL1/dll1.dll
/bin/ExternalDLLs/DLL1/SupportDlls/1.dll
...
/bin/ExternalDLLs/DLL1/SupportDlls/24.dll
/bin/ExternalDLLs/DLL2/dll2.dll
/bin/ExternalDLLs/DLL3/dll3.dll
```

The published folder structure doesn't work with my `DllImport()` declaration. I presume this is because the `DllImport()` is expecting these to be directly underneath `/bin/`.

I don't mind a folder structure underneath `/bin/` if necessary. I also don't mind if every DLL is copied to `/bin/` without any folder structure - though I can't seem to find how to do that since the folder structure is also being copied to `/bin/`.

Can anyone point me on the best approach to overcome this? I don't see an attribute for `DllImport()` to specify a path. I'm sure this is a simple task, but I've never done it before. Hope I explained the problem well enough!

Thx.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/3134808/17034

Comment: @HansPassant This is much more simple than I thought it would be. I can accept this answer if you would create it rather than a comment. Thank you.

Comment: Pretty sure you know everything you need to know to complete the Q+A you started.