# Visual Studio 2008 - Moving files at build to bin/

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2008

**EDIT: This is a VS2008 app written in C#.**

So I have a folder in my solution called

```
_lib/
```

It's where I keep my DLLs so that when I reference them, they get built into the `bin/` folder.

Now I have a new item in my solution. It's a DLL but shouldn't be reference (it's required for a 3rd party app). So on build I want this to be copied from `_lib/` to `bin/` but NOT referenced in the project.

I've included the `_lib/` folder in my app, and for the properties of that DLL I selected always copy. This ALMOST worked, it copies the file with the folder, so my structure looks like:

```
/bin/_lib/thedll.dll
```

Instead of

```
/bin/thedll.dll
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Is this a C++ project? VS2010?

Comment: It's C# and VS2008. I'll edit that info in. :)

Comment: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1014207/copy-to-output-directory-copies-folder-structure-but-only-want-to-copy-files](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1014207/copy-to-output-directory-copies-folder-structure-but-only-want-to-copy-files) has the same question with a few different answers.

Comment: Is the copy a custom build step?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Copy to Output Directory copies folder structure but only want to copy files](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1014207/copy-to-output-directory-copies-folder-structure-but-only-want-to-copy-files)

Comment: You can go ahead and add more tags as this helped me with C++ too

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Try following these steps in Visual Studio:

- Expand the project tree concerned
- Double click the `Properties` element
- In the opened window click the `Build Events` tab
- In the `Post-build event command line` text area place this:

  ```
  xcopy "$(ProjectDir)_lib\file.ext" "$(ProjectDir)bin\$(ConfigurationName)"
  ```
- Open the expected output folder alongside Visual Studio
- Hit <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>B</kbd> to make sure everything is saved and build
- Feel the sense of achievement well up inside you as your file appears
- :)

Oh, and you can now set `Copy to output directory` to `Do not copy`.

Comment: Disappointment: Ahhh my sense of achievement has never been so high! Heh heh :) Thanks for the answer, and it did indeed work. I actually considered doing it as a post build task, but thought "surely there's a setting I can use to just copy it directly" but alas, there's not. Thanks for the confirmation and detailed answer :)

Comment: Just making a small edit - added /Y so it overwrites existing files in the output directory. Without this it causes an error after the first build.