# Copy folder in one Project to bin of another Project in same Solution

Tags: c#

I have a folder that lives in my C# project that I want to be copied to bin after every release build in VS2013.  How can I specify additional items to be copied to bin?

The folder is in another project in the same solution.

For example

```
SoluationA

     ProjectA

     ProjectB
          FolderC
```

I want to copy FolderC to the bin of ProjectA

Comment: who in the world voted this down.  It's a very clear question.  This is something I believe you should be able to do with a csproj am I right?

Comment: What did your search "copy folder to bin" yield? [Copying files into the application folder at compile time](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/747941/), [Copy file(s) from one project to another using post build event…VS2010](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11001822/), [Visual Studio 2008 - Moving files at build to bin/](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4998974/), [How to include other files to the output directory in C# upon build?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16785369/) and so on. This question shows no research effort for a trivial and common question, no need for pity-upvotes.

Comment: @CoffeeAddict Downvote as, per the downvote mouseover, "this question does not show any research effort".

Comment: It should be included as part of the build. Is the folder empty?

Comment: @vc74: You don't actually get that option on a folder.

Comment: MODIFIED please review

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If it *actually* resides in the project (that is, the files are included in the .vcproj file); then you just need to set their "Copy to Output Directory" setting to "Copy if Newer" or "Copy Always". The directory structure will be maintained.

If you need to just *create* a directory, use `MKDIR` in a post-build event to create it.

If you need to copy an existing folder in, use `xcopy` in a post-build event to copy it over.

Comment: Note: you must do the first solution to the files in the folder, you can't set it on the folder itself. If you set a file to one of the two copy options it will retain the folder structure leading up to the project root like the answer says.

Comment: @ScottChamberlain Yes; if you need an *empty* directory, you are effectively stuck with the MKDIR post-build event option.

Comment: the folder resides in a different project in the same solution

Comment: it's not empty, it contains files

Comment: @CoffeeAddict You put it as a line in the "Post-Build Events" box in the project settings. Make sure you use relative paths and the environment variables, or things get hairy fast.

Comment: it resides in a differ project same solution.  See updated post

Comment: so not sure how I'd do this as this xcopy is for the current project copy $(ProjectDir)\Configuration\* $(ProjectPath)\$(OutDir)

Comment: @CoffeeAddict You need a relative path in that instance. If I recall correctly, its relative from the solution root; so it would be xcopy Configuration\FolderC $(ProjectPath)\$(OutDir) If its the project root, ..\Configuration---

Comment: thanks I figured out another way too.  How do you go up one level in the relative pagth?   I tried adding a ..  for example copy  ..\$(ProjectDir)\Company.ProjectToCopyFromName\FolderToBeCodpied\* $(ProjectPath)\$(OutDir).  This will work if I can just go up one level... $(ProjectDir) is including the project I'm copying to in the path and I don't want that

Comment: @CoffeeAddict You'll have to hardcode the other project name, as it doesn't exist as an environment variable. Perhaps we should chat to resolve your confusion?

Comment: sure forgot about the chat, where do you start it?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/63363/discussion-between-bradleydotnet-and-coffeeaddict).

Comment: this works copy  $(SolutionDir)ProjectB\FolderC  $(SolutionDir)ProjectA\$(OutDir)

Comment: thanks all!  I didn't know the syntax well so it took me longer and with your help