# CopyToOutputDirectory - override destination path

Tags: msbuild, copy, customization

I am building a project that has two configurations. Specifically, it has two Entity Data Models, contained as .csdl, .ssdl and .msl files in separate folders, like this:

```
$(ProjectDir)\EDM_1\  <files here>
$(ProjectDir)\EDM_2\  <files here>
```

On build, only one folder should be selected and copied to output directory, this is determined by configuration. And I managed to do it, but got an issue: the files are copied in

`$(OutDir)\EDM_1`   - like they are contained in source tree.
But I want them to be in `$(OutDir)\EDM` - without number, i. e. to have one output folder for two input folders.

I searched the web and found one common solution - to use `AfterBuild` target and `Copy`. It really does copying, but only to given project's output dir. `Copy` does not copy files through the reference hierarchy in solution.

How this can be done?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/a/21534669/499609!