# How to prevent binary file folder also being copied to output dir?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a few class library assemblies from third parties. To help with organisation, I added a new project to my solution specially for these binaries. I didn't just add a solution folder, because I don't like that there is no physical folder there. I also like to to have these in their own project so that if I might add helpers for the original binaries I know where they are.

My project looks as follows:
BinaryProj.csproj
--Lib (folder)
----ab1.all
----bc3.dll
----cd4.dll

All of the above dlls are marked with 'Copy to output directory', but when I compile this project, these dlls are found under `bin/Lib/....dll` instead of 'bin/....dll`. How can I get rid of the damned`Lib`?

Comment: You're looking for [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms165410.aspx)?

Comment: You could also keep them generated in `bin/Lib/....dll` and add a post build event copying the files into `bin/....dll`

Comment: Change the output path in the project properies

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To change the build output directory:

1. List item
2. On the menu bar, choose Project, Appname Properties.
   Choose the Build tab.
3. Choose the Browse button next to the Output path box and specify a new build output directory.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't do this. Sure, you may want to add third-party binaries to a Visual Studio (class library?) project for the overview and ease of management, but you shouldn't copy them to the output directory of that library project. The project doesn't need them, and referencing projects don't need all of them.

Just store the files wherever you want, preferably without putting them in a project, then *reference* the binaries from projects that need them. Then the files will be copied to the `bin` directory of projects that need them:

```
* Solution directory
|
+- ThirdParty
|  |
|  +- SomeAssembly.dll
|
+- Project1
```

Here Project1 will reference `..\ThirdParty\SomeAssembly.dll` and copy that into its own `bin` directory.

If you're sure your way is the way you want, see [Copy to Output Directory copies folder structure but only want to copy files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1014207/copy-to-output-directory-copies-folder-structure-but-only-want-to-copy-files) to control where files are copied to.

Comment: Yeah, I supposed I could create a project purely to get a folder subordinate to the solution, then place the dependencies directly in that folder and simply reference them. They never get output to any `bin` folder other than where they are needed.