# How do I make sure every file in an included directory is copied to the destination in Visual Studio?

Tags: visual-studio-2010

I'm building an application that has quite a few files that need to be included in the destination directory.  So far, there haven't been very many files so I would simply change the settings of each file individually to `Copy to Output Directory :: Copy if newer`.  The problem now is that I'm adding files at an exponential rate.

[image]

Do any of you know how to make all of the files that are sub of the "Some_Directory" have the `Copy to Output Directory :: Copy if newer` set how I want it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cam use a *post-build* event.

Using following posts, I made a *post event* that does exactly what you want:

- [Copying files into the application folder at compile time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/747941/visual-studio-copying-files-into-the-application-folder-at-compile-time)
- [Copy to Output Directory copies folder structure but only want to copy files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1014207/copy-to-output-directory-copies-folder-structure-but-only-want-to-copy-files)
- [Visual Studio adds .dll and .pdb to project after compiling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1013419/visual-studio-adds-dll-and-pdb-to-project-after-compiling/1013561)

Now, you can easily edit *Post-build* events, go to your project settings and go to the Compile tab, now click the *Build Events* and put following line in the *Post-build event command line" text box:

```
xcopy "$(ProjectDir)Test\*.*" "$(TargetDir)Test\\" /E /I /F /Y
```

See this image:
[image: post-build event]

In your case you will have to change "Test" by "some_directory" and that's all.

> There is one caveat, however. This copies every file every time my project builds. The folder that is being copied is over 3MB (I'm developing quite a large project). This makes debugging take quite a long time because every time I do a build it has to move all of the content over. Is there a way to make it only copy over files that have been updated since the last build? This is why I was using the `Copy if newer` option.

You can add the `/D` parameter (you can look that up with `xcopy /?` in your command prompt).

```
/D:m-d-y     Copies files changed on or after the specified date.
             If no date is given, copies only those files whose
             source time is newer than the destination time.
```

Comment: These links show answers that are to vague.  I'm also utilizing Vb.net, not C#.  I need very specific answers and in depth explanations on how to solve my particular situation.

Comment: It is both .NET, really, there is not that much difference. The offered solutions are not that vague, they are pretty clear to me. I updated my post to include the solution, all ready for you. I hope you can use it.

Comment: Hey, that worked really well.  Sorry that I'm so dumb :P.  There is one caveat, however.  This copies every file every time my project builds.  The folder that is being copied is over 3MB (I'm developing quite a large project).  This makes debugging take quite a long time because every time I do a build it has to move all of the content over.  Is there a way to make it only copy over files that have been updated since the last build?  This is why I was using the `Copy if newer` option.  +1 for you for the help so far, though!

Comment: You can add the `/D` parameter (you can look that up with `xcopy /?` in your command prompt).   `/D:m-d-y     Copies files changed on or after the specified date. If no date is given, copies only those files whose source time is newer than the destination time.` I updated the answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can write your own custom **Post-Build event** (Select project -> Properties -> Build Events) with **xcopy** command. You can use $(solution) macro for your solution directory and specify relative path to your files.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue, but the accepted answer didn't solve it. What worked for me was to enable deployment in Local.testsettings (under Solution Items).